# Canon PIXMA TS305 not printing on custom page size

Tags: printing

I have a Canon Pixma TS305 which I use for printing custom size labels of 110x290cm.

The latest linux drivers are from
https://www.canon.sk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_ts_series/pixma-ts305.html?type=drivers&language=sk&os=linux%20(64-bit)

The printer is easy to setup in a local network via driverless dnssd and the install script works fine. Printing works and I am able to add custom paper sizes in the given PPD file in /etc/cups/ppd/.. dir.

Now I am trying to access that printer over VPN. In Ubuntu I installed a new printer via finding the host and selecting IPP or JetDirect protocol. Setup selects the correct driver and I can print a test page.

The problem comes when I try to print to the custom size. I tried specifying the size in the PPD and even printing via the Ubuntu printing system dialog. The printing ends with "Stopped" status in the printer queue. The cups interface on http://localhost:631/ says "filter failed" and the /var/log/cups/error_log gives a summary of recorded messages:

```
**E [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Unable to open raster stream - : Broken pipe**
E [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the /var/log/cups/error_log file for details.
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] The following messages were recorded from 11:29:28 to 11:29:28
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Applying default options...
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Adding start banner page "none".
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Adding end banner page "none".
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] File of type application/pdf queued by "praetorian".
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] hold_until=0
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Queued on "TS305" by "praetorian".
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] time-at-processing=1658568568
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] 3 filters for job:
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] pdftopdf (application/pdf to application/vnd.cups-pdf, cost 66)
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] gstoraster (application/vnd.cups-pdf to application/vnd.cups-raster, cost 99)
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] rastertocanonij (application/vnd.cups-raster to printer/TS305, cost 0)
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] job-sheets=none,none
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] argv[0]="TS305"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] argv[1]="496"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] argv[2]="praetorian"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] argv[3]="Výjazdový zákazkový list-52056.pdf"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] argv[4]="1"
**D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] argv[5]="PageSize=Custom.595.28x841.89** MediaType=plain number-up=1 noCollate noCNGrayscale Duplex=None job-uuid=urn:uuid:c0e309ed-8e9b-3f9f-6f15-c4c21141e27b job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1658568568 time-at-processing=1658568568"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00496-001"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[4]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[8]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@praetorian-Vostro-3500"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.3.1"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[13]="USER=root"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[14]="CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[15]="CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[16]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[17]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[18]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[19]="LANG=en_US.UTF-8"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[20]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/TS305.ppd"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[21]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[22]="CONTENT_TYPE=application/pdf"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[23]="DEVICE_URI=socket://192.168.57.105:9100"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[24]="PRINTER_INFO=TS305"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[25]="PRINTER_LOCATION=office"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[26]="PRINTER=TS305"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[27]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[28]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[29]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[30]="AUTH_I****"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 1421477)
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster (PID 1421478)
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertocanonij (PID 1421479)
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/socket (PID 1421480)
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] PID 1421479 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertocanonij) stopped with status 255 (Unknown error 155)
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] OUTFORMAT=\"(null)\", so output format will be CUPS/PWG Raster
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] pdftopdf: Last filter determined by the PPD: rastertocanonij; FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE: application/vnd.cups-raster => pdftopdf will not log pages in page_log.
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] PDF interactive form and annotation flattening done via QPDF
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Looking up \"192.168.57.105\"...
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] 192.168.57.105=192.168.57.105
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] PID 1421477 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Color Manager: Calibration Mode/Off
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-TS305)
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_TS305
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Calling org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device.Get(ProfilingInhibitors)
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-TS305)
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_TS305
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Calling GetProfileForQualifiers(rgb.plain.600dpi...)
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Found profile /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/profiles/TS305_RGB__
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Calling org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Profile.Get(Filename)
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Use profile filename: \'\'
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Color Manager: ICC Profile: 
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Ghostscript using Any-Part-of-Pixel method to fill paths.
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Ghostscript command line: gs -dQUIET -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dNOINTERPOLATE -dNOMEDIAATTRS -dShowAcroForm -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile=%stdout -sDEVICE=cups -sMediaType=plain -r600x600 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=595 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=842 -dcupsBitsPerColor=8 -dcupsColorOrder=0 -dcupsColorSpace=1 -scupsPageSizeName=A4 -I/usr/share/cups/fonts -c \'<</.HWMargins[9.640000 14.380000 9.359985 8.500000] /Margins[0 0]>>setpagedevice\' -f -_
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[0]=\"CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[1]=\"CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[2]=\"CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[3]=\"CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[4]=\"CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[5]=\"CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[6]=\"CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[7]=\"CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[8]=\"HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[9]=\"PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[10]=\"SERVER_ADMIN=root@praetorian-Vostro-3500\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[11]=\"SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.3.1\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[12]=\"USER=root\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[13]=\"CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[14]=\"CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[15]=\"CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[16]=\"IPP_PORT=631\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[17]=\"CHARSET=utf-8\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[18]=\"LANG=en_US.UTF-8\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[19]=\"PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/TS305.ppd\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[20]=\"RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[21]=\"CONTENT_TYPE=application/pdf\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[22]=\"DEVICE_URI=socket://192.168.57.105:9100\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[23]=\"PRINTER_INFO=TS305\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[24]=\"PRINTER_LOCATION=office\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[25]=\"PRINTER=TS305\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[26]=\"PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[27]=\"CUPS_FILETYPE=document\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[28]=\"FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] envp[29]=\"AUTH_INFO_REQUIRED=none\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Start rendering...
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Processing page 1...
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] hrDeviceDesc=\"Canon TS300 series 1.110\"
**D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Error: /ioerror in --showpage--**
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Operand stack:
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] true   (/tmp/gs_rP8rLZ)   --nostringval--   1   true
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Execution stack:
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   showpage   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   showpage   showpage   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   2   3   %oparray_pop   1989   2   3   %oparray_pop   1977   2   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   1978   4   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   2   1   1   showpage   %for_pos_int_continue   1981   4   7   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   1840   3   9   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Dictionary stack:
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] --dict:739/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:135/256(ro)(G)--   --dict:316/325(ro)(G)--   --dict:31/32(L)--   --dict:6/9(L)--   --dict:6/20(L)--
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Current allocation mode is local
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Last OS error: Broken pipe
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Rendering completed
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] PID 1421478 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) stopped with status 1.
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] prtMarkerColorantValue.1.1 = \"black\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] prtMarkerColorantValue.1.2 = \"color\"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] ATTR: marker-colors=#000000,none
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] ATTR: marker-names=\'\"Canon Black Ink Tank\"\',\'\"Canon Color Ink Tank\"\'
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] ATTR: marker-types=ink-cartridge,ink-cartridge
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] ATTR: marker-levels=-1,-1
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] new_supply_state=0, change_state=ffff
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -developer-low-report
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -developer-empty-warning
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -marker-supply-low-report
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -marker-supply-empty-warning
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -opc-near-eol-report
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -opc-life-over-warning
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -toner-low-report
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -toner-empty-warning
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -waste-receptacle-almost-full-report
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -waste-receptacle-full-warning
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -cleaner-life-almost-over-report
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -cleaner-life-over-warning
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] new_state=0, change_state=ffff
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -media-empty-warning
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -door-open-report
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -media-jam-warning
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -input-tray-missing-warning
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -output-tray-missing-warning
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -marker-supply-missing-warning
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -output-area-almost-full-report
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -output-area-full-warning
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] backendWaitLoop(snmp_fd=5, addr=0x55a5e49deb98, side_cb=0x55a5e2d7c6a0)
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] PID 1421480 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/socket) exited with no errors.
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] End of messages
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] printer-state=3(idle)
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] printer-state-message="Rendering completed"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] printer-state-reasons=none
^C
root@praetorian-Vostro-3500:/etc/cups/ppd# tail -f /var/log/cups/error_log
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -output-tray-missing-warning
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -marker-supply-missing-warning
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -output-area-almost-full-report
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] STATE: -output-area-full-warning
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] backendWaitLoop(snmp_fd=5, addr=0x55a5e49deb98, side_cb=0x55a5e2d7c6a0)
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] PID 1421480 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/socket) exited with no errors.
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] End of messages
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] printer-state=3(idle)
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] printer-state-message="Rendering completed"
D [23/Jul/2022:11:29:28 +0200] [Job 496] printer-state-reasons=none
```

When I try to print to known predefined paper sizes (A4, postcard, ..) the printing works fine. As soon as I change the paper size, this errors show up.

The printer is definitely able to print to the custom size. But for some reason the IPP/JetDirect way tries to intercept and sets wrong document size and fails to apply the filters.

Any chance to get this workign?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution:

I compared the printer capabilities of my previously installed and working dnssd printer with the newly set up remote IPP printer inspired by this threads:

https://super-unix.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-custom-paper-size-processing-not-connected/
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/custom-page-size-problem-773199/

```
root@praetorian-Vostro-3500:/etc/cups/ppd# lpoptions -p Canon-TS300-series-ofic -l
PageSize/Media Size: 3.5x5 3.5x5.Borderless 4x6 4x6.Borderless *A4 A4.Borderless Letter Letter.Borderless Postcard Postcard.Borderless Custom.WIDTHxHEIGHT
InputSlot/Media Source: Auto *Main
MediaType/Media Type: *Stationery Photographic
ColorModel/Print Color Mode: *RGB Gray
cupsPrintQuality/Print Quality: *Normal High
```

and

```
root@praetorian-Vostro-3500:/etc/cups/ppd# lpoptions -p Canon-TS305-ofis -l
MediaType/Media Type: *plain glossygold glossypaper photopaper ijpostcard postcard
CNGrayscale/Grayscale Printing: True *False
PageSize/Page Size: Letter *A4 4x6 4x6.bl l l.bl Postcard Postcard.bl
Duplex/Duplex Printing: *None
Resolution/Output Resolution: *600dpi
ColorModel/Color Model: *rgb
```

where the newly set up printer was clearly missing the option **Custom.WIDTHxHEIGHT** and thus the print commands in other than standard page sizes had to fail.

I was confused by the difference while installing the same device. Then I noticed that there is a printer driver name difference in the http://localhost:631/ cups client while trying to modify the printer again and again. The earlier working printer driver name was follwed by

**... IPP Everywhere ™**

https://istopwg.github.io/ipp/evefaq.html

I assume the original install.sh script provided by Canon would somehow take advantage of the IPP Everywhere capabilities, but it couldn't detect my remote printer in a different subnet. So I searched for a way to force cups detect and add the printer remotely and found this Oracle document

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36821/gmfou.html

with usefull commands, like

```
lpinfo --make-and-model Canon -m
```

which provides a long list of supported Canon printers alltogether with the TS300 series PPD

```
canonts300.ppd Canon TS300 series Ver.5.50
lsb/usr/canonts300.ppd Canon TS300 series Ver.5.50
```

**BUT** interrestingly this driver too

```
everywhere IPP Everywhere
```

Putting everything together and adding a new printer with commands provided by the Oracle doc was like this:

```
lpadmin -p TS305 -E -v ipp://192.168.57.105:631 -m everywhere
```

I am again printing with the custom size set up in PPD. Even more, now I see extended printer capabilies compared to those from the original Canon driver.
Hope this will help somebody.